# get a most appropriately matching string from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

> Suppose, I've a string - `"abcfile.csv"` & an array of strings -

`["abc.csv", "abcf.csv", "cde.doc", "abcdefile.csv", "abcfi.csv"]`

Here, I want to partially match given string `"abcfile.csv"` with the array of strings and It should give me an element from array as an output in which **the most no. of consecutive characters are matching.**.

> That is, in this example, It should return **"abcfi.csv"** from the array as it has the more no. of matching consecutive characters with **"abcfile.csv"**.

I tried with some string equality methods but it doesn't help. (`includes`, `===` etc).

---

***Update:***

---

I'm trying to apply the solution given by ***@Alexandru-Ionut Mihai*** on my actual data, but mess up with some cases -

```js
let arrayFiles = ["Account_Summary_(LS)_Mar'17.csv", "Additions and Changes_MACD (LS)_Mar'17.csv", "Adjustment and Payments_Mar'17.csv", "CDR LD.csv", "CDR's_-_All_(LS)_Mar'17.csv", "CSR.csv", "Customer_Service_Records_(LS)_Mar'17.csv", "Discounts, Promotions and Fees (LS)_Mar'17.csv", "Equipment Other Charges (LD)_Mar'17.csv", "Inventory Circuits (LD)_Mar'17.csv", "Local Usage Detail (LS)_Mar'17.csv", "Other_Carrier_Detail_(LS)_Mar'17.csv", "Service Summary (LD)_Mar'17.csv", "Tax Detail (LD)_Mar'17.csv", "Tax_Detail_(LS)_Mar'17.csv"];

let arrayTable = ["CSR.csv", "Tax Detail LD.csv", "Tax Detail LS.csv", "Additions and Changes MACD LS.csv", "Adjustment and Payments.csv", "CDR LS.csv", "CDR LD.csv", "Discounts Promotions and Fees LS.csv", "Equipment Other Charges LD.csv", "Inventory Circuits LD.csv", "Local Usage Detail LS.csv", "Other Carrier Detail LS.csv", "Audio Conference.csv", "Toll Free.csv", "Other Charges.csv", "Account Statement.pdf", "Extended Area service.csv", "Local Message Services.csv", "Report - Charges by Line taxes.csv", "Billing Adjustments.csv", "Usage Details.csv", "Account Statement.pdf"];

let string = arrayFiles[11];    // "Other_Carrier_Detail_(LS)_Mar'17.csv"

let found;
while (string.length > 0) {
    let elem = arrayTable.find(a => a.includes(string));
    if (elem) {
        found = elem;
        break;
    }
    string = string.slice(0, -1);
}
console.log(found);
```

Here, I expect it to return arrayTable[12] i.e. **"Other Carrier Detail LS.csv"**, but it is returning **"Equipment Other Charges LD.csv"**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php ?

Comment: What if searched string is 'abcfi.csv' and possible files are `abcfile.csv` and `abcfixy.csv`. Or search string 'abc' and files `abc.csv` and `abc.doc`. Your idea isn't good, try to do it better (eg. offer possible values by ajax request, ...)

Comment: this item `"abc.csv"` has also *the more no. of matching consecutive characters with "abcfile.csv".* relatively to its length. The question is too broad

Comment: Does the match have to start at the beginning? Does `abcd` match better `iabcd` or `abc`? BTW: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem - for a general picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `while` loop and check if exists array items which contains the desired string.

After every iteration you should `slice` the string without last char and so on..

`abcfile.csv -> abcfile.cs -> abcfile.c -> abcfile. -> abcfile -> abcfil -> abcfi -> abcf -> abc -> ab -> a ->""`

With this method you will find out the most appropriately matching string from an array.

```js
let string = "abcfile.csv";
let array = ["abc.csv", "abcf.csv", "cde.doc", "abcdefile.csv", "abcfi.csv"];
let found;
while(string.length > 0){
  let elem = array.find(a => a.includes(string));
  if(elem){
    found = elem;
    break;
  }
  string = string.slice(0,-1);
}
console.log(found);
```

Comment: can it be done without using a `break` statement? Please see my updated question. I've updated it with actual data.

Comment: without break will match the last one which pass the test.

Comment: You can use replce method in order to replace blank spaces, `,` or `_` sign.